# Trying to sort a dictionary but then it gets mixed up again

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, sorting, struct

Trying to sort this property by its key `let data: [String: [Interests]]` but it gets mixed up again after saving the data. How can I solve this issue.

Here is the struct model

```
// MARK: - InterestsData
struct InterestsData: Codable {
   let message: String?
   let data: [String: [Interests]]


   func sortedByKey() -> InterestsData {
       let sortedKeys = data.keys.sorted()
    
       print("SORTED KEYS:",sortedKeys) // Sorted Alphabetically 
    
       var sortedData: [String: [Interests]] = [:]
            
       for key in sortedKeys {
           sortedData[key] = data[key]
       }
    
       print("SORTED KEYS WITH DATA ", sortedData) //Now keys not sorted
    
       return InterestsData(message: message, data: sortedData)
   }


}



// MARK: - Interests
   struct Interests: Codable {
       let id: Int
       let name: String
       let isSelected: Int?
   }
```

Comment: Dictionary are unordered so you can't sort them, from the documentation: _Every dictionary is an unordered collection of key-value pairs_. You need to sort the keys like you have done in your code every time you want to display or access the values of your dictionary in a specific order. (If you need to do this a lot you could have a stored property for the sorted keys)

Comment: See OrderedDictionary, which is part of the swift-collections package: https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md

Answer (score 0):

As dictionary is unordered collection (it cannot be sorted/ordered), you can only to use array of custom KeyValuePairs:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

struct InterestsData: Codable {
   let message: String?
   let data: [CustKeyValuePair<String, [Int]>]
    
   func sortedByKey() -> InterestsData {
       let sortedData = data.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
    
       return InterestsData(message: message, data: sortedData )
   }
}

struct CustKeyValuePair<T1, T2>: Codable where T1: Codable, T2: Codable {
    let key: T1
    var value: T2
}

////// TESTING of solution on real data:

let data = [
    "1asdf" : [1,2,3],
    "5asdf" : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "4asdf" : [1,2,3,1,2],
    "3asdf" : [1,2,3,2],
    "2asdf" : [1,2,3,0]
].map{ CustKeyValuePair(key: $0.key, value: $0.value) }

let a = InterestsData(message: "message", data: data )

let b = a.sortedByKey().data.map{ $0.key }

print(b)
```

Console output:

```
["1asdf", "2asdf", "3asdf", "4asdf", "5asdf"]
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

so data is sorted

Comment: As `Codable` is not really required for the key-value pairs why don't you use the [built-in](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs) struct?

Comment: @vadian Because of conflicts in code, it's trying to change type from `KeyValuePair<T1,T2>` to `Dictionary<T1:T2>.Element` and it's not castable to `KeyValuePair<T1,T2>` -  I donno why, so it was easier/faster to create custom struct :)

Answer (score 0):

Standard swift dictionaries are not ordered, however Apple provides the [Collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) library which contains an `OrderedDictionary` that maintains the order the keys were inserted and can be sorted manually:

```swift
import OrderedCollections

var dict = OrderedDictionary<String, [Interests]>()
dict["9"] = [Interests(id: 9, name: "Lorem", isSelected: nil)]
dict["1"] = [Interests(id: 1, name: "Ipsum", isSelected: nil)]
dict["5"] = [Interests(id: 5, name: "Dolor", isSelected: nil)]
dict.sort { lhs, rhs in
    lhs.key < rhs.key
}
print(dict)
/// Order will be 1,5,9
```